# Is there a way to have Snow Leopard match the scrolling behavior of Lion?

Tags: snow-leopard, macos

I can see that I will quickly come to love the Lion way of scrolling.

My brain will soon become rewired to think of moving the content with my gestures instead of moving the controller down to slide content up in my fixed viewport.

I have several macs that need to remain on Snow Leopard for some time, and would love any suggestions on how I might change them to better fit Lion's new model for scrolling.

Comment: Four days of lion and I am totally worthless on older macs and whatever random PC I use. I fear I'm ruined for life already :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This post](http://daringfireball.net/linked/2011/07/20/scrollvetica) by John Gruber outlines several possibilities:

For OSX:

- [Scrollvetica](https://github.com/correia/Scrollvetica)
- [Scroll Reverser](http://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/)

For Windows:

- [An AutoHotkey hack](http://www.howtogeek.com/57542/how-to-get-the-worst-os-x-lion-feature-in-windows-reverse-scrolling/)

On the Mac side, Scroll Reverser looks nice in the menu bar, is free, and works from Tiger to Snow Leopard (10.4 - 10.6).

[image: scroll reverser in action]

Comment: Scrollvetica is perfect. I feel I watch the gruber far too obsessively, but that one slipped right by my radar. Information overload and I don't care about that yet - thanks for the alternatives.

Comment: Scroll Reverser worked for me, thanks for the recommendation.