# How can I change scroll direction in Snow Leopard?

Tags: snow-leopard, settings, preferences, macos

I've gotten so used to the Lion natural scrolling that using (for lack of a better term) unnatural scrolling in Snow Leopard and earlier is very annoying. Is there any way I can reverse it for OSes before Lion?

Comment: Hmm. [Is there a way to have Snow Leopard match the scrolling behavior of Lion?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18538/is-there-a-way-to-have-snow-leopard-match-the-scrolling-behavior-of-lion)

Comment: Oh, sorry, bmike, that didnt show up in the searching I did.

Comment: No worries - just the other answer had more options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can, with [Scroll Reverser](http://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/). It's a free app that sits in your menu bar (you can hide it if you want). It works all the way back to OS X Tiger.

[image]

Comment: That picture might make a nice addendum to the answer on the linked question. Perhaps at the end with the mention of tiger through snow leopard and the free bit :-)

Comment: How did you get the other icons to hide for the screenshot? Is that an app?

Comment: @timothymh My guess is Photoshop. I didn't actually take the picture. ;-)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. (I don't think that's it, though, as you can see the stars shining through the menu bar... where'd you find it?)

Comment: @timothymh On the Scroll Reverser site.

Comment: @timothymh Likely Photoshop as even though there *are* stars, they're repeated very unnaturally, see the pair repeated 11 times to the right of the menu item.

Comment: @grgarside definitely — not sure what 2012 me was thinking!